# Is there any way to interact with the shell but keep the same session open?

Tags: shell-escape, write, unix

I'm preparing some course material (PDF) for a tutorial that involves the Unix command line. Because I strive for automation (some call that laziness), I've written a little package that allows me, using `\write18` (with `--shell-escape`) and the `verbatim` package, to

1. run commands (e.g. `ls`) at the command *during* compilation of my `.tex` document and typeset them in my document,
2. redirect the resulting `stdout` and `stderr` to external files,
3. input those external files for typesetting the `stdout` and `stderr` in my `.tex` document.

However, my understanding is that each invocation of`\write18` opens and closes its own shell session. This is unfortunate, as it requires some contorsions and code duplication. In particular,

- all the shell variables defined during one session are unavailable in the next;
- I have to `cd` to the same directory at the beginning of each `\write18` in order to land back in the same directory I was in at the end of the preceding `\write18`.

See my toy example below.

Is there any way I could interact with the shell during a `pdflatex` run, but somehow keep a shell session open from one `\write18` call to the next? Or is there a better approach that would suit my needs?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

First, initialise the repository.

% pretend that the following is an environment that both
% - runs commands at the CL
% - typesets them in the .tex document
\immediate\write18{%
  cd $HOME/Desktop;
  mkdir myrepo;
  cd myrepo;
  git init;
}

Let's see what git has to say...

\immediate\write18{%
  # I'm back in $HOME :(
  # I have to cd to $HOME/Desktop/myrepo, here, but I'd like to avoid it...
  cd $HOME/Desktop/myrepo;
  git status
  # ...
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need for code duplication, the initial steps can be put into a macro.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, I could write a script for `cd`, for instance, but what about shell variables?

Comment: I guess you want to try `pythontex`

Comment: @egreg I'll have a look at the `pythontex` sourcecode.

Comment: The variable settings can either also be handled by a reused macro or the variable settings has to be set in the parent shell, before the TeX job starts there.

Comment: I don't really understand. Why do you need the 'Let's see' in between the two writes. Why can't you do all of the shell stuff and then say that? If the actual scripts are giving you stuff you are then typesetting so that you need the 'Let's...' in between, can't you have the shell output the appropriate text as well?

Comment: @cfr Good question. The answer is that it would involve code duplication: I would have to rewrite my shell commands both in a shell script *and* in my `.tex` file. I want to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: It should be possible to add shell support to `pythontex`...I already added Ruby, Julia, and Octave support with minimal modifications. I can see if it's possible.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `org-mode` and how it generates reproducible documents.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\immediate\write18{echo pwd > /tmp/zzpipe}

\texttt{\input{result.txt}}

\immediate\write18{echo cd > /tmp/zzpipe}

\immediate\write18{echo pwd > /tmp/zzpipe}

\texttt{\input{result.txt}}

\immediate\write18{echo 'FOO=wibble' > /tmp/zzpipe}

\immediate\write18{echo 'echo FOO is $FOO' > /tmp/zzpipe}

\texttt{\input{result.txt}}

\end{document}
```

a) set up a "server" to accept the commands, I just use a named pipe:

```
$ cd /tmp


$ mkfifo zzpipe

$ while true ; do eval `cat /tmp/zzpipe` >/tmp/result.txt  ; done
```

then run the above tex file (in `/tmp` or arrange `result.txt` gets written somewhere else) the output should be as shown.

This is on windows with cygwin bash, other commandlines will be similar but may need different quoting conventions.
and as you may see the `cd` and the setting of `FOO` survives from one write to the other.

Comment: Thanks David. Please give me some time to study your solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have added basic bash support to `pythontex`...ended up taking less than 20 lines of code. To use this, you will need the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).  You will need to use the standard `pythontex` 3-step compile whenever you have new bash code that needs to be executed (run LaTeX, run the PythonTeX script, run LateX).  When you don't have new code that needs to be executed, you can just run LaTeX by itself.  Since this doesn't use `\write18`, you don't need shell-escape (code execution is handled by the PythonTeX script).

Everything seems to be working, but you will have to let me know if you find any bugs.  Error line numbers should be correctly synchronized with those of the code that is executed.

Here's a sample document, with the output shown below.  `\stdoutpythontex` is verbatim by default, so the format doesn't have to be specified like it does with `\printpythontex` (or the equivalent `\stdoutpythontex`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[makestderr, usefamily=bash]{pythontex}
\setpythontexfv{numbers=left, firstnumber=last}

\begin{document}

A block of bash...
\begin{bashblock}
myvar="myvar's value"
echo $myvar
\end{bashblock}
...with output:
\printpythontex[verbatim]

Another block, accessing the previous variable...
\begin{bashblock}
echo "In another LaTeX environment later on..."
echo $myvar
\end{bashblock}
...with output:
\printpythontex[verbatim]

A block with an error.
\begin{bashblock}
echo "In another LaTeX environment later on..."
echo $myvar
lsERROR
\end{bashblock}
Stdout:
\printpythontex[verbatim]
Stderr:
\stderrpythontex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! I just suggested to look at PythonTeX, not to extend it! ;-)

Comment: +1 Cool. I'll give that a go, and I'll get back to you. Is your implementation compatible with other shells as well (e.g. `zsh`)?

Comment: @Jubobs It should be compatible with most shells. All it relies on is the existence of `cd` and `echo`, plus `>&2` as a way to echo to stderr. To actually use it with other shells, though, you would need to specify the shell. Running the PythonTeX script with the command-line option `--interpreter bash:zsh` should work (that allows you to set which executable is actually called). Or it would be very simple to create a set of environments for other shells, for example, `zshblock` etc. That way, you could access multiple shells in the same document.